# Realm access from incorrect thread in Espresso

Tags: android, multithreading, realm, kotlin, android-espresso

Before each espresso test, I have an annotation `@Before` where I initialize my `RealmManager.realm`.

Code snippet of my `object Realm`:

```
init {
    Realm.init(SaiApplication.context)
    val builder = RealmConfiguration.Builder().schemaVersion(SCHEMA_VERSION)
    builder.migration(runMigrations())
    if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) builder.encryptionKey(getOrCreateDatabaseKey())
    if (SaiApplication.inMemoryDatabase) builder.inMemory()
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(builder.build())
    try {
        errorOccurred = false
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        errorOccurred = true
        realm = Realm.getInstance(RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .schemaVersion(SCHEMA_VERSION).name(errorDbName).build())
        e.log()
        deleteRealmFile(realm.configuration.realmDirectory)
    }
}
```

But when I run my tests, I get next error:

> Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created

So how i can correctly init my realm in my tests?

One of the [solutions](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3808#issuecomment-262298950) that I found interesting, create a fake init realm.

Comment: You should specify the line where you get this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i do.
I just added next function in my AppTools, which check package with tests:

```
fun isTestsSuite() = AppResources.appContext?.classLoader.toString().contains("tests")
```

Then modifed init of Realm:

```
 init {
    Realm.init(AppResources.appContext)
    val builder = RealmConfiguration.Builder().schemaVersion(SCHEMA_VERSION)
    builder.migration(runMigrations())
    if (!isTestsSuite()) builder.encryptionKey(getOrCreateDatabaseKey()) else builder.inMemory()
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(builder.build())
    try {
        errorOccurred = false
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        errorOccurred = true
        realm = Realm.getInstance(RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .schemaVersion(SCHEMA_VERSION).name(errorDbName).build())
        e.log()
        deleteRealmFile(realm.configuration.realmDirectory)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To manipulate the UI thread's Realm instance from your UI tests, you need to initialize the Realm instance on the UI thread using `instrumentation.runOnMainSync(() -> {...});`.

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    Instrumentation instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
    instrumentation.runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // setup UI thread Realm instance configuration
        }
    });
}
```